# TypeError: get_params() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' on RandomSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn

**Problem**

Running a KNeighborsClassifier with OneVsRestClassifier. Already have several other classifiers working perfect with OneVsRestClassifier, but when I try the pattern of code that worked for other RandomSearchCV for classifer, this once hits a snat on Error Type.

I have parameters for the KNeighborsClassifier classifier: n_neibgors, weights, algorithm params, initialized with object and not a class, e.g., . Yes, the get_params() is missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.

**Code**

```
param_grid = {
    'n_neighbors': [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,11,12,14,20],
    'weights': ('uniform', 'distance', 'callable', 'None'),
    'algorithm': ('auto', 'ball_tree', 'kd_tree', 'brute', 'auto'),
    'leaf_sizeint': [10,20,30,40,50,60,80,120]
}

ovr_KNN_model = OneVsRestClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier)
ovo_KNN_model = OneVsOneClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier)

ovr_KNN_grid_param = RandomizedSearchCV(ovr_KNN_model, param_grid, cv=5, n_jobs=3, error_score="raise")
ovo_KNN_grid_param = RandomizedSearchCV(ovo_KNN_model, param_grid, cv=5, n_jobs=3, error_score="raise")
ovr_KNN_model_model_fit = ovr_KNN_grid_param.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
```

**Error Location**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[51], line 2
      1 ## scores
----> 2 ovr_KNN_model_model_fit = ovr_KNN_grid_param.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train) 
      Search:\n", ovr_KNN_model_model_fit.best_estimator_)
```

**Error Message**

```
TypeError: get_params() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

**Error Trace**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[51], line 2
      1 ## scores
----> 2 ovr_KNN_model_model_fit = ovr_KNN_grid_param.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train) 
      3 ovo_KNN_model_model_fit = ovo_KNN_grid_param.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train) 
      5 print("\n OneVsRest Classifier KNN best estimator across Randomized Search:\n", ovr_KNN_model_model_fit.best_estimator_)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:891, in BaseSearchCV.fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    885     results = self._format_results(
    886         all_candidate_params, n_splits, all_out, all_more_results
    887     )
    889     return results
--> 891 self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    893 # multimetric is determined here because in the case of a callable
    894 # self.scoring the return type is only known after calling
    895 first_test_score = all_out[0]["test_scores"]

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:1766, in RandomizedSearchCV._run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1764 def _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates):
   1765     """Search n_iter candidates from param_distributions"""
-> 1766     evaluate_candidates(
   1767         ParameterSampler(
   1768             self.param_distributions, self.n_iter, random_state=self.random_state
   1769         )
   1770     )

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py:838, in BaseSearchCV.fit.<locals>.evaluate_candidates(candidate_params, cv, more_results)
    830 if self.verbose > 0:
    831     print(
    832         "Fitting {0} folds for each of {1} candidates,"
    833         " totalling {2} fits".format(
    834             n_splits, n_candidates, n_candidates * n_splits
    835         )
    836     )
--> 838 out = parallel(
    839     delayed(_fit_and_score)(
    840         clone(base_estimator),
    841         X,
    842         y,
    843         train=train,
    844         test=test,
    845         parameters=parameters,
    846         split_progress=(split_idx, n_splits),
    847         candidate_progress=(cand_idx, n_candidates),
    848         **fit_and_score_kwargs,
    849     )
    850     for (cand_idx, parameters), (split_idx, (train, test)) in product(
    851         enumerate(candidate_params), enumerate(cv.split(X, y, groups))
    852     )
    853 )
    855 if len(out) < 1:
    856     raise ValueError(
    857         "No fits were performed. "
    858         "Was the CV iterator empty? "
    859         "Were there no candidates?"
    860     )

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:1054, in Parallel.__call__(self, iterable)
   1051     self._iterating = False
   1053 with self._backend.retrieval_context():
-> 1054     self.retrieve()
   1055 # Make sure that we get a last message telling us we are done
   1056 elapsed_time = time.time() - self._start_time

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py:933, in Parallel.retrieve(self)
    931 try:
    932     if getattr(self._backend, 'supports_timeout', False):
--> 933         self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
    934     else:
    935         self._output.extend(job.get())

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py:542, in LokyBackend.wrap_future_result(future, timeout)
    539 """Wrapper for Future.result to implement the same behaviour as
    540 AsyncResults.get from multiprocessing."""
    541 try:
--> 542     return future.result(timeout=timeout)
    543 except CfTimeoutError as e:
    544     raise TimeoutError from e

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py:446, in Future.result(self, timeout)
    444     raise CancelledError()
    445 elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 446     return self.__get_result()
    447 else:
    448     raise TimeoutError()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py:391, in Future.__get_result(self)
    389 if self._exception:
    390     try:
--> 391         raise self._exception
    392     finally:
    393         # Break a reference cycle with the exception in self._exception
    394         self = None

TypeError: get_params() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

**Data y**

```
11719    4
25835    4
13523    5
49       4
19381    4
        ..
27642    5
28628    5
4506     5
40663    4
38826    4
Name: label, Length: 3146, dtype: int64
```

**Data X

```
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Should you instantiate `KNeighborsClassifier`? ie. `KNeighborsClassifier()`

Comment: thanks. I must have missed that. I had all my others correct, e.g, ovr_softmax_model = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(multi_class = 'multinomial')), but somehow missed this an panicked...